# Sum up two variables in a long-format dataframe with tidyverse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a simple data frame in a tidy format:

```
  group variable               value
  <fct> <chr>                  <dbl>
1     fishers_here         100
1     money_per_fisher     2000
1     unnecessary_variable 10
2     fishers_here         140
2     money_per_fisher     8000
2     unnecessary_variable 304
3     fishers_here         10
3     money_per_fisher     9000
....
```

for each group I'd like to have the variable "total money in group" which is just `fishers_here` * `money_per_fisher`; basically I'd like it to look like this:

```
  group variable               value
  <fct> <chr>                  <dbl>
1     fishers_here         100
1     money_per_fisher     2000
1     unnecessary_variable 10
1     TOTAL_MONEY          200000

....
```

Is there a simple way to get this done with tidyverse?
By simple I mean without having to filter, summarise, add the variable column back in and then join the two now separate  dataframes.

Comment: let me rephrase it for added clarity

Comment: No. The easiest would be to summarize and merge. None of the verbs other than the joins make it possible to add new rows. You could maybe use the `do()` but not sure how recommended that is any more.

Comment: Is there a typo in row 6, where it should be group 1? or are there actually duplicate rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `spread`, do the multiplication and then `gather` back up. Note I'm assuming that there is a typo in the group number in row 6 as I commented, where it should be group 2 instead of group 1. If that's not the case, then some additional cleaning steps are needed. You can also sort your resulting rows however you want (e.g. to put the rows for each group back together)

```r
library(tidyverse)
tbl <- read_table2(
  "group variable               value
  1     fishers_here         100
1     money_per_fisher     2000
1     unnecessary_variable 10
2     fishers_here         140
2     money_per_fisher     8000
2     unnecessary_variable 304
3     fishers_here         10
3     money_per_fisher     9000"
)
tbl %>%
  spread(variable, value) %>%
  mutate(total_money_in_group = money_per_fisher * fishers_here) %>%
  gather(variable, value, -group)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 3
#>    group variable               value
#>    <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
#>  1     1 fishers_here             100
#>  2     2 fishers_here             140
#>  3     3 fishers_here              10
#>  4     1 money_per_fisher        2000
#>  5     2 money_per_fisher        8000
#>  6     3 money_per_fisher        9000
#>  7     1 unnecessary_variable      10
#>  8     2 unnecessary_variable     304
#>  9     3 unnecessary_variable      NA
#> 10     1 total_money_in_group  200000
#> 11     2 total_money_in_group 1120000
#> 12     3 total_money_in_group   90000
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

An option would be to `filter` the 'money_per_fisher', 'fishers_here', grouped by 'group', `summarise` to get the `prod` of 'value', bind the rows with the original data and `arrange` by 'group'

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
   filter(variable %in% c('fishers_here', 'money_per_fisher')) %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(variable = "total_money_in_group", value = prod(value)) %>% 
   bind_rows(tbl, .) %>% 
   arrange(group)
# A tibble: 11 x 3
#   group variable               value
#   <int> <chr>                  <dbl>
# 1     1 fishers_here             100
# 2     1 money_per_fisher        2000
# 3     1 unnecessary_variable      10
# 4     1 total_money_in_group  200000
# 5     2 fishers_here             140
# 6     2 money_per_fisher        8000
# 7     2 unnecessary_variable     304
# 8     2 total_money_in_group 1120000
# 9     3 fishers_here              10
#10     3 money_per_fisher        9000
#11     3 total_money_in_group   90000
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L),
 variable = c("fishers_here", 
 "money_per_fisher", "unnecessary_variable", "fishers_here", "money_per_fisher", 
 "unnecessary_variable", "fishers_here", "money_per_fisher"), 
value = c(100L, 2000L, 10L, 140L, 8000L, 304L, 10L, 9000L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your output I think this is a possible solution:

```
df %>% 
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(value = prod(value))
```

Edit: If you want a column on the original dataset you can use `mutate` instead of `summarise`

Comment: thanks for this; it won't work since it'll multiply over variables that are not of interest. Of course I could filter first, but I was hoping to avoid having to do all that work and then having to left_join the two dataframes later on.